# pygame NameError: name 'wall' is not defined

Tags: python, pygame

maze game - previous said walls was not defined until I moved walls=[] out of the game loop(while True:)

```
class Wall (object):
    def __init__(self,pos):
        walls.append(self)
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(pos[0], pos[1], 16, 16)



    x = 0
    y = 0

    for row in level:
        for col in row:
            if col == 'W':
                Wall((x, y))
            if col == "E":
                end_rect = pygame.Rect (x, y,16,16)
            x = x + 16
        y = y + 16
        x = 0
```

Comment: `walls` is not defined here. Where is `walls=[]`?

Comment: that isn't the whole code. walls = [] is defined at the top although that might not be the right place for it.

Comment: Where is the error that you're getting? I don't see a `wall` to be undefined.

Comment: You can't instantiate an object inside the class's scope outside the methods. The code on the bottom should be global. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14841203/python-instantiate-class-within-class-definition) for more.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, half your code should be global, this is a scope issue. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14841203/python-instantiate-class-within-class-definition) for more.

```
class Wall (object):
    def __init__(self,pos):
        walls.append(self)
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(pos[0], pos[1], 16, 16)

x = 0
y = 0

for row in level:
    for col in row:
        if col == 'W':
            Wall((x, y))
        if col == "E":
            end_rect = pygame.Rect (x, y,16,16)
        x = x + 16
    y = y + 16
    x = 0
```

Basically, the code in the class body is executed before the class is even created; thus, you would not be able to instantiate an object of the given class inside the class scope.